# WIkidata: Getting multiple participants in Wikidata query result

Tags: sparql, wikidata

Question: Hi, all. I found an example script from Wikidata example pages,
but in the result, every case shows only ONE participant, while most of them have many participants. Is there a way to show all the participants labels? I don't understand why (and how) only one is selected to appear.

```
SELECT distinct ?race ?raceLabel ?musherLabel
WHERE
{
{ ?race wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q1968664 . }
UNION { ?race wdt:P31/wdt:P641* wd:Q1968664 . }
?race p:P710 ?musherS .     #here we have a full statement, not a value
?musherS ps:P710 ?musher .  #here we get the value
FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?musherS pq:P1352 ?rank }
FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?musherS pq:P793 ?event }
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "fr,en" }
}
ORDER BY ?raceLabel
```

[Result](https://query.wikidata.org/embed.html#%23added%20before%202016-10%0ASELECT%20distinct%20%3Frace%20%3FraceLabel%20%3FmusherLabel%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%09%7B%20%3Frace%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279*%20wd%3AQ1968664%20.%20%7D%0A%09UNION%20%7B%20%3Frace%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP641*%20wd%3AQ1968664%20.%20%7D%0A%09%3Frace%20p%3AP710%20%3FmusherS%20.%20%09%23here%20we%20have%20a%20full%20statement%2C%20not%20a%20value%0A%09%3FmusherS%20ps%3AP710%20%3Fmusher%20.%20%09%23here%20we%20get%20the%20value%0A%09FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%20%3FmusherS%20pq%3AP1352%20%3Frank%20%7D%0A%09FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%20%3FmusherS%20pq%3AP793%20%3Fevent%20%7D%0A%09SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22fr%2Cen%22%20%7D%0A%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3FraceLabel)

**Edit:**

Here (https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Qualifiers) I read:

> **For multiple values**
>
> Example of a statement consisting of multiple values for one property
>   Wikidata allows for items to have multiple values per property. For certain statements—such as the children of a person or the official languages of a country—it is perfectly reasonable to have multiple values which may not be qualified in any way.
>
> However, it is also possible for items to have statements with multiple values when only really one value is expected for the property. When an item ideally should have only one value—for example, the population of a city—but has multiple values, then qualifiers should be used in order to indicate further information about the values, such as when the values date from, how they were determined, what exactly they refer to, and so on.

So does it mean there is NO way to just get them all (label values)?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you're asking, but you get a single row for each matching result in the RDF graph. I mean, you get multiple rows for the same race, right?

Comment: That has nothing to do with the qualifiers. One row per possible binding of the variables. If you want all participants in the same row, `group by` + `gorup_concat` is the way to go

Comment: Well, for instance, when you run that query, in the first result, you get 'Beverly Masek' as MusherLabel, while there are actually many participants if you check the page about the race. I'd like to know if there's a way to get all the participants labels in results.

Comment: Oh okay, I will check it out now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single row per race you have to make use of `group by` in combination with the aggregate function `group_concat`.

#### Query:

```sql
SELECT distinct ?race ?raceLabel (group_concat(?musherLabel; separator="; ") as ?mushers)
WHERE
{
    { ?race wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q1968664 . }
    UNION 
    { ?race wdt:P31/wdt:P641* wd:Q1968664 . }
    ?race p:P710 ?musherS .     #here we have a full statement, not a value
    ?musherS ps:P710 ?musher .  #here we get the value
    FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?musherS pq:P1352 ?rank }
    FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?musherS pq:P793 ?event }

    SERVICE wikibase:label { 
     bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". 
     ?musher rdfs:label ?musherLabel . 
     ?race rdfs:label ?raceLabel . 

  }
}
GROUP BY ?race ?raceLabel
ORDER BY ?raceLabel
```

#### Output:

```
+------------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                   race                   |     raceLabel      |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     mushers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q19361352 | Q19361352          | Brett Bruggeman; Brett Bruggeman; Brett Bruggeman; Brett Bruggeman; Bryce Mumford; Bryce Mumford; Bryce Mumford; Bryce Mumford                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q18577453 | 1993 Iditarod      | Beverly Masek                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q18577456 | 1996 Iditarod      | Rick Swenson                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q23014078 | 2016 Iditarod      | Robert Redington; Hans Gatt; Anna Berington; DeeDee Jonrowe; Noah Burmeister; Ed Stielstra; Ken Anderson; Tim Pappas; Ellen Halverson; Jodi Bailey; Jeff King; Brent Sass; Becca Moore; Robert Bundtzen; Karin Hendrickson; Sigrid Ekran; Melissa Owens; Rob Cooke; Scott Smith; Kim Franklin; Elliot Anderson; Scott Janssen; Paige Drobny; Ketil Reitan; Justin Savidis; Aliy Zirkle; Cim Smyth; Dag Torulf Olsen; Linwood Fiedler; Kristin Bacon; Monica Zappa; Billy Snodgrass; Tore Albrigtsen; Mats Pettersson; Kristin Knight Pace; Cindy Gallea; Ray Redington; Katherine Keith; James Volek; Joar Leifseth Ulsom; Jim Lanier; Martin Koenig; Ryne Olson; Nathan Schroeder; Hugh Neff; Tom Jamgochian; Larry Daugherty; Lisbet Norris; Zoya DeNure; Ralph Johannesen; Allen Moore; Michael Williams; Sarah Stokey; Rick Casillo; John Baker; Paul Gebhardt; Dallas Seavey; Mary Helwig; Michelle Phillips; Martin Buser; Kristy Berington; Jan Steves; Ryan Redington; Trent Herbst; Jason Campeau; Alan Eischens; Mitch Seavey; Wade Marrs; Richie Diehl; Nicolas Petit; Charley Bejna; Patrick Beall; Lance Mackey; Robert Sørlie; Jessie Royer; Miriam Osredkar; Kelly Maixner; Noah Pereira; Travis Beals; Geir Idar Hjelvik; Matthew Failor; Peter Kaiser; Lars Monsen; Jason Mackey; Cody Strathe |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q22093610 | 2016 Kuskokwim 300 | Pato Geron                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to apply it to: https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fincident%20%3Flabel%20%3Fparticipant%20%3FparticipantLabel%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fincident%20%28wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%29%20wd%3AQ132821.%0A%20%20%3Fincident%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fincident%20wdt%3AP710%20%3Fparticipant.%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alimit%2010 (before grouping)

Comment: But why wouldn't this one work (grouping applied)? Well ofc I must've done something wrong but... : https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fincident%20%3Flabel%20%28group_concat%28%3FparticipantLabel%3B%20separator%3D%22%3B%22%29%20as%20%3Fparticipant%29%0A%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fincident%20%28wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%29%20wd%3AQ132821.%0A%20%20%3Fincident%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fincident%20wdt%3AP710%20%3Fparticipant.%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fparticipant%20%3FparticipantLabel%0AORDER%20BY%20%3FparticipantLabel